# ambassador service stays "pending"

Tags: kubernetes, ingress

Currently running a fresh "all in one VM" (stacked master/worker approach) kubernetes `v1.21.1-00` on Ubuntu Server 20 LTS, using

- cri-o as container runtime interface
- calico for networking/security

also installed the kubernetes-dashboard (but I guess that's not important for my issue ). Taking this guide for installing ambassador: https://www.getambassador.io/docs/edge-stack/latest/topics/install/yaml-install/ I come along the issue that the service is stuck in status "pending".

`kubectl get svc -n ambassador` prints out the following stuff

```
NAME               TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
ambassador         LoadBalancer   10.97.117.249    <pending>     80:30925/TCP,443:32259/TCP   5h
ambassador-admin   ClusterIP      10.101.161.169   <none>        8877/TCP,8005/TCP            5h
ambassador-redis   ClusterIP      10.110.32.231    <none>        6379/TCP                     5h
quote              ClusterIP      10.104.150.137   <none>        80/TCP                       5h
```

While changing the `type` from `LoadBalancer` to `NodePort` in the service sets it up correctly, I'm not sure of the implications coming along. Again, I want to use ambassador as an ingress component here - with my setup (only one machine), "real" loadbalancing might not be necessary.

For covering all the subdomain stuff, I setup a wildcard recording for pointing to my machine, means I got a CNAME for `*.k8s.my-domain.com` which points to this host. Don't know, if this approach was that smart for setting up an ingress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gets the IP address when you change `type` to `NodePort` because it uses a node's IP address. It can't do it with `LoadBalancer` because you are running a kubernetes cluster on VM and it doesn't have any `LoadBalancers` available.
Tutorial is designed for `minikube` or clouds users. You can see it here:

> Note: If you are a Minikube user, Minikube does not natively support
> load balancers. Instead, use minikube service list

I also got this reproduced on a cluster which was set up with `kubeadm` on my VMs.

`kubectl get services -n ambassador`

```
NAME               TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)                      AGE
ambassador         LoadBalancer   10.105.124.148   <pending>       80:30000/TCP,443:31375/TCP   1m15s
ambassador-admin   ClusterIP      10.101.160.245   <none>          8877/TCP,8005/TCP            1m15s
ambassador-redis   ClusterIP      10.110.123.244   <none>          6379/TCP                     1m15s
```

One of the simplest solutions which can help you is using `metal load balancer`. This was specifically designed for bare metal clusters to give them a loadbalancing ability.

Here's a [link](https://metallb.universe.tf/installation/#installation-by-manifest) to `metallb` installation.

Keep in mind that:

> The installation manifest does not include a configuration file.
> MetalLB’s components will still start, but will remain idle until you
> define and deploy a configmap.

Next part is to set up a [ConfigMap](https://metallb.universe.tf/configuration/). To do so you need to create a ConfigMap with appropriate protocol you want to use. I used a simple `layer 2` config:

metallb-configmap.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: metallb-system
  name: config
data:
  config: |
    address-pools:
    - name: default
      protocol: layer2
      addresses:
      - 192.168.1.240-192.168.1.250
```

And apply it with `kubectl apply -f metallb-configmap.yaml`.

Immediately after I did it, ambassador service received the IP address:

```
NAME               TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)                      AGE
ambassador         LoadBalancer   10.105.124.148   192.168.1.241   80:30000/TCP,443:31375/TCP   4m2s
ambassador-admin   ClusterIP      10.101.160.245   <none>          8877/TCP,8005/TCP            4m2s
ambassador-redis   ClusterIP      10.110.123.244   <none>          6379/TCP                     4m2s
```

Simple test with `curl 192.168.1.241` works!

If you have any questions about `ingress` doesn't work, consider asking this in a different question. See [best practices for stack community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741).

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you.

Comment: If I don't have access to an IP pool, is there anything else I can do with MetalLB?